# Is this the correct setting of short coil pitch configuration?

Tags: induction-motor, winding, stator

So I tried to visualize 12 slots 2 poles induction motor and I used a coil pitch of 150 degrees as is the convention. Each pole will use an interval of 12/2=6 slots. 6 slots is a complete electrical turn of 180 degrees. We should find that 150 degrees correspond to 6x(150/180) = 5 slots. It means we will use 5 slots and leave 1 slot empty. The only thing we need to know is now the phase pitch. Each phase should have a 120 degrees pitch: 6x(120/180) = 4 slots will be the phase difference. So, let's summarize:

12 slots machine. 6 slots a pole. The coil pitch is 5 slots, 1 slot is left empty. Between each phase, there will be 4 slots pitch (we will jump 4 slots, and start to wind from the fifth slot).

[image: Stator winding]

<sub>Image adapted from: [ResearchGate - Hsiao, Chun-Yu & Yeh, Sheng-Nian & Hwang, Jonq-Chin. (2011). A Novel Cogging Torque Simulation Method for Permanent-Magnet Synchronous Machines. Energies. 4. 10.3390/en4122166.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264845149_A_Novel_Cogging_Torque_Simulation_Method_for_Permanent-Magnet_Synchronous_Machines) ([figure 1](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Structure-of-a-10-pole-12-slot-PMSM_fig1_264845149))</sub>

Is my illustration correct? I tend to think I did a mistake because 6 slots are left unused, meanwhile, different phases use their slots commonly which is a dangerous thing (?) in case of a phase phase short-circuit (think about coil winding's thin isolation melting because of heat).